# The comment with a link to an example removed (by the moderator, I assume)

Tags: discussion, comments

I commented on [I can run playbook on user but not on crontab](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/738385/i-can-run-playbook-on-user-but-not-on-crontab#738385)

My comment: "See [Run Ansible playbooks in cron](https://ansible-runner-role.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example1-cron.html#example-1-run-ansible-playbooks-in-cron)

The potential answer to the question is very complex and is out of scope here. I was surprised by finding that my comment was deleted without any notification. I would like to know why. Also to avoid this in the future if this is my fault.

Comment: Answers should not be posted in the comments. Did you post an answer in the comments?

Comment: @Mast looks like the issue was "Link only comment", probably someone flagged. OP posted a new comment with context and it's not deleted.

Comment: I know. I'm not sure there is an answer in the link. I think: "The potential answer to the question is very complex and is out of scope". See the link and tell me. Would you accept this as an answer?

Comment: There are currently no deleted comments associated with that question.  There is a deleted answer with a comment from you though. The answer was not deleted by a moderator, but by the answer owner.

Comment: Thank you. I apologize if this is my mess. I added the link to the comment again.

Comment: I have one more question. Imagine, I remember I commented on some question or answer and I can't find my comment anymore either in the questions and answers or in the lists of my comments. How should I know what happened?

Comment: Comments are "temporary post-it notes" intended to clarify the Question or Answer they're attached to. I thank that SE intends for comments to disappear; as such, there's currently no way for you to view your deleted comments.

Answer (score 5):

Your comment wasn't deleted. The *answer* was deleted by the person who posted it, and since you had left the comment under the answer, the deletion of the answer also removed your comment:

[image: screenshot of the deleted answer]

That said, you should always expect comments to be deleted. They are supposed to be ephemeral and, ideally, ask for clarifications or provide new info that can be integrated into the answer/question. So if you want something to stay, post a full answer, not a comment. For more details, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment:

> Comments are temporary "Post-It" notes left on a question or answer. They can be upvoted (but not downvoted) and flagged, but do not generate reputation. There's no revision history, and when they are deleted they're gone for good.

Comment: With the caveat that “gone for good” isn’t true ;-).